# Jump back to index using `scrollToIndex` a second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

(This question pertains to the [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) library)

I have a component that uses `<List>` to display several categories of items. The resulting output looks something like:

```
Jump to: Planets, Nebulae

PLANETS
- Mercury
- Venus
- Jupiter
- ...
NEBULAE
- Horsehead
- Ant
- Boomerang
- ...
```

I'd like to use the "Jump to" links to scroll to the start of the corresponding section in the list. If I scroll around some I'd like subsequent clicks of the jump link to take me back to the section.

The first time I click the "Nebulae" link it works fine, but nothing happens on subsequent clicks. I assume this is because `scrollToIndex` is a prop and doesn't change after the first click. I've tried using `forceUpdateGrid` but it doesn't seem to reset the scroll position.

Is there a way to jump to the same index multiple times in a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of the props approach. (react-virtualized only manually scrolls when it detects a *new* prop. Otherwise, users would be unable to scroll with their mouses once an initial prop was set.)

One way to work around this is to unset the `scrollToIndex` prop once you've set it (so that if you then reset it, it will still be a new value). Temporarily unsetting it (aka resetting it to `undefined`) will have no affect on the list either so you should be fine.

Comment: That's what I wound up with. I was hoping I'd missed something in the API that would be a little more straightforward. Thanks for the input.

Comment: No problem. I used to have an Api method for scroll-to as well but that didn't feel like a very React way to do things, since it required a ref, etc.